# How to update a column that matches the criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that is selecting particular data based on criteria:

```
SELECT p.customer_id
     , p.product_id
     , p.unit_price
     , c.updated_profile 
  FROM imp_subscriptionitems p
  LEFT 
  JOIN imp_customerdata c 
    ON p.customer_id=c.user_id
 WHERE c.updated_profile = 1
   AND p.product_id = 253
```

How can I update the `p.unit_price` column where the criteria matches and change it to `2`?

Comment: Note that this is an INNER JOIN, so you can remove the LEFT keyword

Comment: You can use `UPDATE`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EXISTS` to update it as follows:

```
UPDATE IMP_SUBSCRIPTIONITEMS P
   SET P.UNIT_PRICE = 2
 WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID = '253' 
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
  FROM IMP_CUSTOMERDATA AS C WHERE P.CUSTOMER_ID = C.USER_ID
   AND C.UPDATED_PROFILE = '1' )
```

**Note**: Your original query is not doing what you are expecting. It is not doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead it is doing `INNER JOIN`

You can also use multi-table update as follows:

```
update imp_subscriptionitems i,
(SELECT p.customer_id
     , p.product_id
     , p.unit_price
     , c.updated_profile 
     , p.pk_column -- replace pk_Column with actual primary key column name of imp_subscriptionitems 
  FROM imp_subscriptionitems p
  LEFT  JOIN imp_customerdata c 
    ON p.customer_id=c.user_id and c.updated_profile = 1
   where p.product_id = 253) derived_Data
set i.unit_price = 2
where p.pk_column = i.pk_column -- replace pk_Column with actual primary key column name of imp_subscriptionitems
```

And now direct update on the table using join is also possible.
But that is already updated in another answer so now I am skipping the details for that in it.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm terrible at queries so thats good to know. Where it has `Select 1`, will that only do 1 row every time I run the query? I just need it to run through the entire table. Maybe misunderstanding what its doing.

Comment: No you can use `select *` or `select null` . it is not relevant actually. `EXISTS` just checks if records in the sub-query exists or not

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation of your current select query to an update would be an update join:

```sql
UPDATE imp_subscriptionitems p
INNER JOIN imp_customerdata c 
    ON p.customer_id = c.user_id
SET
    p.unit_price = 2
WHERE
    c.updated_profile = 1 AND
    p.product_id = 253;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE imp_subscriptionitems p

LEFT JOIN  imp_customerdata c ON c.user_id = p.customer_id

SET p. unit_price =2

WHERE c.updated_profile ='1' AND
p. product_id ='253'